# Units in the ring of functions $\mathbb Z^+\to \mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\mathbb Z^+$ be the monoid of positive integers over usual multiplication and $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z^+]$ be the set of functions from $\mathbb Z^+$ to $\mathbb Z$. For $f, g ∈ \mathbb Z[\mathbb Z^+]$ and $x ∈ \mathbb Z^+$, deﬁne $(f + g)(x) := f (x) + g(x)$, and $$(f g)(x):=\sum_{(a,b)\ \in \ {(\mathbb{Z}^+)}^2  : \ ab \ =\ x} f(a)g(b),$$ which makes $\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z^+]$ a ring.

$(1)$ I need to prove, first of all, that if $f(1)=\pm 1$, then $f$ is a unit in this ring. I found out that the identity of this ring is the function $I$ defined as $I(x)=1$ if $x=1$ and $I(x)=0$ otherwise. But I couldn't prove that every $f$ with $f(1)=\pm 1$ is invertible.

As a draft, suppose $f(1)=1$ and $g$ is the inverse of $f$. Particularly, $(fg)(1)=f(1)g(1)=I(1)=1$. Then, $g(1)=1$. I did the same for $x=2,3,4$, but couldn't determine $g$.

$(2)$ Besides, I'd to prove that if $f∈\mathbb Z[\mathbb Z^+]$ is multiplicative, (that is, if $f(1)=1$ and $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$, if $m$ and $n$ are coprimes), then its inverse is multiplicative too.

If someone has any hint, I'd appreciate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the inverse of $f$ by induction.

As in your draft, $(fg)(1) = f(1)g(1)$ should be 1, therefore necessarily $g(1) = f(1)$.

Let us try for $2$:
$(fg)(2) = f(1)g(2) + f(2)g(1)$ should be 0, then necessarily $g(2) = \frac{-f(2)g(1)}{f(1)} = -f(2)g(1)f(1)$ because $f(1) \in \{-1,1\}$.

Let us suppose that we have defined $g(k) \ \ \forall k < n$. Then
$$
(fg)(n) = 0 = \sum_{ab=n} f(a)g(b) = f(1)g(n) + \sum_{ab=n \\ b < n} f(a)g(b)
$$
therefore
$$g(n) = - \frac{\sum_{ab=n \\ b < n} f(a)g(b)}{f(1)} = - f(1)\sum_{ab=n \\ b < n} f(a)g(b)
$$

In particular, when $p$ is prime, $g(p) = -f(p)$.

Comment: thank you for this very detailed solution!

Comment: Could you please put this question as an "Edit" after your main question? Thx

Comment: For (2), I changed $g(n)$ to $g(mn)$ in the penultimate line of your solution and I tried to get $g(m)g(n)$ on the second member, admitting $m$ and $n$ coprimes, but I didn't succeed.